# What does "blanding" mean?

Tags: meaning, nouns, neologisms

What does *blanding* mean in any culture or language?

Comment: I am not finding "blanding" used as anything but a surname. Can you use it in a sentence or tell us where you saw it? Edit: Okay, I found one. See answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found one reference for "blanding" in a [list of buzzwords or potential lingo](http://www.buzzwhack.com/buzzcomp/indb.htm):

> blanding: Branding schemes that strip out any uniqueness in a corporate identity in order to appear to a larger audience. The resulting look: bland.

It appears to be a variation of "bland" to the extent that it means some amount of "blanding" has occurred and the result of the blanding is a bunch of stuff that is now bland:

> They are busy blanding our website.

I would advise against using this word anywhere outside of causal conversation. Wait a year or so and see if it catches on.

Comment: how will it catch on if everyone is waiting to see if it catches on ;)

Comment: @Matt: The lesser proles may mete out neologisms at their will. Our responsibility is much higher. [/sarcasm]

Comment: "A" for effort.